# passing php variables to ajax url

Tags: php, ajax, variables

*updated

The problem is there a multiple variables and i can't pass the php echo.  and i can't just run the script within the php due to the " conflict

```
<?php
.....other stuff

 $i=0;
 while ($i < $num) {

$id=mysql_result($result,$i, "StudentID");
$first=mysql_result($result,$i,"First");
$last=mysql_result($result,$i,"Last");
$date= date("Y.m.d");
echo "<div id=\"list\"><div id=\"id\">$id</div><div id=\"name\"> $first $last  
<button onclick=\"addHit($id,$first,$last,$classname,$day,$times,$date)\">Checkin</button></div></div>  ";

$i++;
}

echo"</div></div></div></div>";

?>
<script>
function addHit(id, first, last, classname, day, times, date)
{
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "checkinuser.php",
   data: "id=id&first=first&last=last&classname=classname&day=day&times=times&date=date",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); //Anything you want
   }
 });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you can't have PHP directly in the HTML, so you need to escape all those variables in a PHP code block.  If this were my code though, I'd consider refactoring a bit, so that I could use JSON encoded parameters, e.g.:

```
<?php
    $rawData = array('id'=>$id, 'first'=>$first, 'last'=>$last, ... );
    $hitData = json_encode($rawData);
?>

<button onclick="addHit(<?php echo $hitData ?>)">Checkin</button>

function addHit(inputData)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkinuser.php",
        data: inputData
        success: function(msg) {
            alert( "Checked In! " + msg ); 
        }
    });
}
```

In response to your edit, if you want to keep the params the way you have them, I'd modify your while loop:

```
<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

    $id=mysql_result($result,$i, "StudentID");
    $first=mysql_result($result,$i,"First");
    $last=mysql_result($result,$i,"Last");
    $date= date("Y.m.d");
?>
<div id='list'>
    <div id='id'>
        <?php echo $id?>
    </div>
    <div id='name'>
        <?php echo "$first $last" ?>
        <button onclick='addHit( <?php echo "$id,$first,$last,$classname,$day,$times,$date" ?> )'
            Checkin
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<?php 
    $i++;
}
?>
```

The goal here is to make it easier to read/write, so separating static code (e.g. HTML) from dynamic code as much as possible can be a good thing.  One big advantage is that you don't have to worry about escaping quotes like you do, though a disadvantage is having a fair number of `<?php>` blocks.

Also note that you're setting id='id' for all these divs, which won't work since they'll all share one id when id's need to be unique on a given page.  You probably want to `echo $id` there too.

Similarly, there's no reason to have `echo"</div></div></div></div>";` - move that outside the PHP block and just leave it as HTML.

Finally, in your javascript, you're data parameter is the literal string:

```
"id=id&first=first&last=last&classname=classname&day=day&times=times&date=date"
```

This won't work as id will literally be 'id', first will be 'first', etc.

You need to either use the method I have above (where you pass the whole parameter), or build up the object to pass as your data param.   `.ajax()` will take objects, so I'd make it an object, and pass that, e.g.:

```
function addHit(id, first, last, classname, day, times, date)
{
inputData = { id: id, first: first, etc, etc}
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "checkinuser.php",
   data: inputData,
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); //Anything you want
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: awesome that looks a lot cleaner (sorry im still learning)  what's the correct way to do the data in the java part

Comment: Modified to include the javascript (note that java and javascript are not interchangeable terms).  Hope that helps!

Comment: the only problem now is i'm getting an unexpected identifier. not sure which one is causing that

Comment: Check the error line, and if necessary, start echoing things one at a time to narrow it down, e.g. `echo $id; echo $first; echo $last;`, etc . . . one of them will eventually be the one that's causing you grief; if you put each echo on it's own line, when it errors, you'll know exactly which variable is undefined

Comment: working now had to add '' for each variable wihtin the echo. thank you so much for all the help you are amazing!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working - make sure to accept an answer if you get one that works for you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the data look alike:

```
data: "id="+id+"&first="+first+"&last="+last+"&classname="+classname+"&day="+day+"&times="+times+"&date="+date,
```

You can also use the following format:

```
data : { id : id, first : first, last : last, classname : classname, day : day, times : times, date : date }
```

plus what mimiz said.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert PHP variables into other code directly.  Try `echo`ing them.

```
<button onclick=\"addHit('<?php echo $id.","$first.",".$last.",",$classname.",".$day.",".$times.",".$date; ?>')\">Checkin</button>
```

Comment: how would i do that if its in like
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$id=mysql_result($result,$i, "StudentID");
$first=mysql_result($result,$i,"First");
$last=mysql_result($result,$i,"Last");
$date= date("Y.m.d");





echo "<div id=\"list\"><div id=\"id\">$id</div><div id=\"name\"> $first $last  
 <button onclick=\"addHit('$id,$first,$last,$classname,$day,$times,$date')\">Checkin</button></div></div>  ";

$i++;
}

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<button onclick=\"addHit(<?php echo " '$id', '$first' ,'$last','$classname','$day', '$times','$date'"; ?>)\">Checkin</button>
```

Regards;

mimiz

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
type: "POST",
```

for this:

```
type: "GET",
```

You should pass the variables and receive them in your PHP code by GET, since it is passing by url.

Answer (score -1):

addHit('$id,$first,$last,$classname,$day,$times,$date') 
must be
addHit($id,$first,$last,$classname,$day,$times,$date)

(tnx to Musa )

data: "id=id&first=first&last=last&classname=classname&day=day&times=times&date=date"
must be
data: "id=$id&first=$first&last=$last&classname=$classname&day=$day&times=$times&date=$date"

Comment: The URL parameter string can't have PHP in it, as it's part of the javascript code; if he wants to keep it the way it is, he'd have to build the string using the parameters he passed to the JS function, e.g. `'id=' + id + '&first=' + first`, etc etc